# Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, …) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, excel, date, quantmod

I use a data set imported from excel:

```
OBX <- read_excel("C:/Users/neri_/Desktop/OBX Weekly Return.xlsx")

         Date          OBX
1   2010-12-28    0.0071366
2   2010-12-29  4.97265e-05
3   2010-12-30  -0.00452489
4   2011-01-03   0.00896603
5   2011-01-04   -0.0101488
6   2011-01-05   0.00520143
7   2011-01-06 -0.000422917
8   2011-01-07  -0.00301145
9   2011-01-10  -0.00341996
10  2011-01-11     0.013326
11  2011-01-12   0.00882484
```

I'm struggling with this error message,

> "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format", 
>   which I'm encountering when I'm trying to run the code:

```
weeklydata<-to.weekly(OBX).
```

I want to convert daily data data to weekly data, how do I modify the date format, so I can run the to.weekly command?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want to convert the data from a month-based format like  2012-12-30 to a week-based format like 2012-52-6? By the way, be sure to test around the year ends.

Comment: Please consider taking a moment to read more about formatting your posts, as that will help everybody trying to help. For example, use code blocks (for code, obviously) and blockquotes for error messages. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I just want to convert the daily prices to weekly prices. Normally, this isn't a issue when I download stock prices directly from Yahoo Finance through Quantmod. However, the problem arises when I import the data from an excel file.

Comment: I willl update my answer in a few seconds with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `date2ISOweek()` from the `ISOweek` package. Using `stringr` for pattern updating and `dplyr` to produce the week-results; The code would be like this, after loading the packages.

```
library(ISOweek)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# mocking up some data 
OBX <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2010-12-28", "2010-12-29", "2010-12-30", "2010-12-31", "2011-01-03", "2011-01-04"),
  OBX = 101:106
)

# transform form month- to week-based and trim some
OBX$dateWeek <- date2ISOweek(OBX$Date)

# get rid of the preceeding "W", next drop day-of-week
OBX$dateWeek <- stringr::str_replace(OBX$dateWeek, "-W", "-")
OBX$dateWeek <- stringr::str_replace(OBX$dateWeek, "-.$", "")

# sum per week and print
OBX %>% 
  group_by(dateWeek) %>%
  summarise(weekSum = sum(OBX))

# the results of the mocked data
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  dateWeek weekSum
     <chr>   <int>
1  2010-52     410
2  2011-01     211
```

Please let me know whether this is an answer fitting your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I tried your code and I don't think it is the best fit for the answer  I am looking for I'm afraid. As I mentioned earlier, this example works completely fine:                                                     #download data from Yahoo Finance

Answer (score 0):

Convert with `as.Date` function:

```
 mydate<-"2010-12-28 0.0071366"
 mydate<-as.Date(mydate,"%Y-%m-%d")
 format(mydate,"%Y-%U")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this solved my issue. I tried to use your code and then run to.weekly command. But I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to R. I saved the file with the name

```
gdpOz <- read_excel("C:/Users/stand/Documents/1.Excel/GDP_2013-18.xlsx",sheet="Sheet1")
```

it gave the same error it is finicky and unpredictable with `read.excel`,
So I tried this to convert,

```
Date.POSIXlt(Oz[23,],format , tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d")
```

and many other combinations blindly without success,
What I found was that excel file save as below saved the file as general text which proved completely unmanageable no matter what.
[Excel save as xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaX34.png)

However if you save as a csv file after converting to short date format as below[excel short date csv format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INfaV.png)

Then use this command in R

```
Oz2 <- read.csv.zoo("C:/Users/stand/Documents/1.Excel/gdpOz.csv")
```

It converts without any worries,
the problem lies in excels date format with xlsx files, and R much prefers csv files.
For some reason everytime you save or convert any files, if you try and resave the same file,you have to change the name of the file otherwise it never works, no matter what.
Most people who are not spreadsheet technicians or power users probably never encounter too many excel problems with R, or maybe they get it every time? Who knows?