# as.xts "Character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" [R]

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I'm trying to convert a date series `data$Date` in the data frame below to a time series data type, but I keep getting this error below. I've made sure I have a date format before I try to convert, so I don't understand why the conversion is not happening.

```
> data["Date"] <- as.Date(data[,4], format="%d/%m/%Y")
> data["Date"] < as.xts(data["Date"])
> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

str(data)
    'data.frame':   91867 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ Industry                     : Factor w/ 53 levels "","Accounting and Tax",..: 7 38 45 7 48 8 16 30 30 47 ...
     $ Date                         : Date, format: "2015-01-05" "2015-01-05" "2015-01-05" ...
```

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105369/character-string-is-not-in-a-standard-unambiguous-format) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451832/error-in-as-posixlt-characterx-tz-character-string-is-not-in-a-standard), and tried their solutions but neither of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  An xts object is data and an index.  You're trying to create an xts object with just an index, which you can do but I doubt it's what you want.  And putting an xts object in a data.frame column is not the intended way to use xts objects, so you should expect unexpected behavior.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I did not realize it was and index and data ... which makes a lot of sense now. Thank you for the clarification.